# Azure functions and Microsoft graph webhoooks

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions, webhooks

I am trying to create a subscription with the MS graph using Azure functions and handle the webhooks. I have created two apps, one for subscribing and another for handling the webhook. But i am unable to successfully connect to graph. I am getting the following exception while creating subscription.

"InvalidOperationException: The graph token is missing an oid. Check your Microsoft Graph binding configuration."

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the AAD token grabbed by the extension is lacking an oid (ObjectId).

As found [in this AAD token documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims), the oid

> Contains a unique identifier of an object in Azure AD. This value is immutable and cannot be reassigned or reused. Use the object ID to identify an object in queries to Azure AD.

When using the ClientCredentials (also known as Application Identity) mode of the AAD or Microsoft Graph extension bindings, we would expect the oid value to be the service principal of your application. If this is missing, there is likely an error with how your function app's application identity is configured against AAD.

If everything looks correct there, file an issue against the Graph Extension repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension), and we will work to reproduce this issue and see if this is a bug or a configuration error.

Answer (score 0):

In the application settings in the function settings you should switch the function extension version value to beta. They are working on native graph integration which is going to simplify a lot those kind of scenarios and those new function triggers are only available in preview so far.